# HDMI out of streaming Fairplay Encrypted HLS stream via AVPlayer works iOS 8 but frozen picture on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I would like to know if there anything to fix this problem we have with HDMI out on iOS 7.1 only:

We have a Video on Demand app that we want people to be able to use with Airplay or HDMI via the Lightning HDMI cable. We support both iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.x. We have enabled `allowsExternalPlayback` on our AVPlayer.

We use Fairplay Encrypted HLS streams for our videos and these work fine on playback on the device (iOS 7 & 8), Airplay via the Apple TV (iOS 7 & 8) and HDMI out on iOS 8. However on iOS 7 devices when you plug in the Lightning-HDMI cable into the device whilst the video is playing on the device and TV, the TV just shows a single frame of the video and is paused (AVPlayer rate:0). The same happens when you plug it in before you play the video when you start the video on the device.

Unfortunately you can't run the xCode debugger as you need the usb cable plugged into the device. The device logs are not very helpful.

```
Oct 24 13:14:46  iapd[177] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>: /SourceCache/iapd/iapd-1386.10.43/iapd/EAManager.mm:-[EAManager _takeClientAssertionsForAccessoryConnection]-1607 client (null)
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>: AccessoryInfo = {
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>:     IAPAppAccessoryNameKey = Apple Digital AV Adapter;
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>:     IAPAppAccessoryManufacturerKey = Apple;
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>:     IAPAppAccessoryModelNumberKey = A1438;
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>:     IAPAppAccessoryFirmwareRevisionKey = 7.1.0 (11D7155);
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>:     IAPAppAccessoryHardwareRevisionKey = 1.0.0;
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>: } // End AccessoryInfo
Oct 24 13:14:47  mediaserverd[29] <Notice>: [13:14:47.083] <<< neroendpoint >>> nmanager_discoveryHandler: mediaserverd detected a Nero USB device
Oct 24 13:14:47  mediaserverd[29] <Notice>: 2014-10-24 01:14:47.083479 PM [AirPlay] Inhibit AirPlay Screen: yes
Oct 24 13:14:47  backboardd[31] <Notice>: IOMFB setting virtual mode: 0 0
Oct 24 13:14:47  backboardd[31] <Notice>: IOMFB setting virtual mode: 0 0
Oct 24 13:14:47  backboardd[31] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: openGated (0xffffff809072ca00 current 0xffffff8000900000 ID 1 dev f6 (force f0)) cl registered = 1 (clock 0 H5speed 0 H5f 65535)
Oct 24 13:14:47  iapd[177] <Warning>: ERROR - /SourceCache/iapd/iapd-1386.10.43/iapd/IAPPortManager.mm:__accessoryPortManagerInterest - 69 no transport found for portNumber 1
Oct 24 13:14:47  mediaserverd[29] <Notice>: [13:14:47.527] <<<< FigVirtualDisplaySinkOctavia >>>> octaviaSink_PushFrame: mediaserverd started mirroring to Nero
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: virtual void AppleMobileADBE0::mieEnable(bool, bool), Pixel-Backlight Modulator: 0
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: void DPBDriver::bypass(), DPB Bypassed 
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: STOP sent 2 enc 2 dropped 0 I 1 P 1 P->I 0 B 0 re-encI 0 re-encP 0 should-be-dropped 0 HSH5 0 (stats 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: closeGated (0xffffff809072ca00) cl left: 0
Oct 24 13:14:47  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: openGated (0xffffff809072ca00 current 0xffffff80008db000 ID 2 dev f6 (force f0)) cl registered = 1 (clock 0 H5speed 0 H5f 65535)
Oct 24 13:14:48  MyApp[172] <Warning>: [1414152888.370] sid=440785955 Monitor: player state changes to BUFFERING (6).
Oct 24 13:14:48  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: Silent switch is off, route: HDMI
Oct 24 13:14:48  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: Updating resume milestone to: 28.339840
Oct 24 13:14:48  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: EpisodeResumeDetail: Setting last milestone to 28
Oct 24 13:14:51  MyApp[172] <Warning>: springstreams (iOS 1.1.0)> http status code: 200 - no error
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff80906d4a00]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: STOP sent 364 enc 364 dropped 0 I 1 P 363 P->I 0 B 0 re-encI 0 re-encP 0 should-be-dropped 0 HSH5 0 (stats 363 1 0 0 0 0 0 0)
Oct 24 13:14:53  kernel[0] <Debug>: VXE380: closeGated (0xffffff809072ca00) cl left: 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  mediaserverd[29] <Error>: 13:14:56.964 ERROR:     [0x1024b0000] >aq> 1584: Exiting because mConverterError is 'nope' (0x2000 req, 0x0 primed)
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: IOAudioCodecsUserClient::setProperties : compressionType = 0
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: targetLevel = 0x00000000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: cutFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  kernel[0] <Debug>: IOAudioCodecsUserClient[0xffffff808f7c4000]::setProperties: boostFactor = 0x3f800000
Oct 24 13:14:56  mediaserverd[29] <Error>: 13:14:56.965 ERROR:     [0x1024b0000] >aq> 1605: failed ('nope'); will stop (8192/0 frames)
Oct 24 13:14:57  mediaserverd[29] <Error>: 13:14:57.254 ERROR:     [0x1024b0000] >aq> 1584: Exiting because mConverterError is 'nope' (0x20000 req, 0x0 primed)
Oct 24 13:14:57  mediaserverd[29] <Error>: 13:14:57.255 ERROR:     [0x1024b0000] >aq> 1605: failed ('nope'); will stop (131072/0 frames)
Oct 24 13:14:57  MyApp[172] <Warning>: [1414152897.282] sid=440785955 Monitor: player state changes to PLAYING (3).
Oct 24 13:14:57  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: ###### handleDurationDidChange, time now 2783.040000
Oct 24 13:14:57  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: Updating resume milestone to: 28.338840
Oct 24 13:14:57  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: EpisodeResumeDetail: Setting last milestone to 28
Oct 24 13:14:59  MyApp[172] <Warning>: [1414152899.456] sid=440785955 Monitor: player state changes to PAUSED (12).
Oct 24 13:14:59  MyApp[172] <Warning>: <redacted> + DEBUG: EpisodeResumeDetail: Setting last milestone to 28
Oct 24 13:15:00  fud[174] <Notice>: Nothing left to do, exiting.
Oct 24 13:15:00  fud[174] <Notice>: Successfully serialized to disk
```